# Redux "success" doesnt clear after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So on my page there is the ability to `create`, `update` and `delete`. I am using Redux in the following way to see whether these worked or not.

```
    const incomingCallCreate = useSelector(state => state.incomingCallCreate)
    const { loading: loadingCreate, error: errorCreate, success: successCreate} = incomingCallCreate

    const incomingCallDelete = useSelector(state => state.incomingCallDelete)
    const { loading: loadingDelete, error: errorDelete, success: successDelete } = incomingCallDelete

    const incomingCallUpdate = useSelector(state => state.incomingCallUpdate)
    const { loading: loadingUpdate, error: errorUpdate, success: successUpdate } = incomingCallUpdate
```

Then below in my JSX I have the following:

```
{successCreate && <Message variant='success'>Incoming Call Created</Message>}
{successDelete && <Message variant='success'>Incoming Call Deleted</Message>}
{successUpdate && <Message variant='success'>Incoming Call Updated</Message>}
```

and in my `useEffect` I have the 3 values as dependencies:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (userInfo) {
          dispatch(listIncomingCalls())
        } else {
          history.push('/login')
        }
    }, [userInfo, history, successCreate, successUpdate, successDelete])
```

So the problem I have is that if I create something, the "created success" alert will show. Then if I delete something the "delete success" alert will show but the create one will remain. Id like for only the most recent one to display. I have tried adding a reset for each action in my reducer and in my useEffect, reset the other 2 if one is true. But it didn't work.

If all 3 are showing and I click the refresh button on my browser, they go. So I thought the useEffect re-rendering the page would do the same but I guess not?

Comment: On JSX have you tried something like: `{successCreate && !successDelete  && !successUpdate && <Message variant='success'>Incoming Call Created</Message>}` ?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito and if the latest thing done was an update or delete?